# hook_comment is not working for update operation in drupal

Tags: drupal-6, comments

I am trying to modify comment body before saving or updating in drupal 6. I am trying to use following code:

```
function mymodule_comment(&$a1, $op) {
switch ($op) {
    case 'insert':
    case 'update':
             $a1['comment'] = myfunction($a1['comment']);
        break;

}
```

}

But it is not updating the comment body after save. I also tried following code and it works:

```
function mymodule_comment(&$a1, $op) {
switch ($op) {
    case 'insert':
            $a1['comment'] = myfunction($a1['comment']);
            comment_save($a1);
        break;

}
```

}

But in case of update it is showing error:

```
function mymodule_comment(&$a1, $op) {
switch ($op) {
    case 'update':
             $a1['comment'] = myfunction($a1['comment']);
             comment_save($a1); 
        break;

}
```

}

Any idea or help is very appreciated.

Comment: The reason - comment is already saved on update action, so you cannot change the comment. you should read about  `hook_comment_form_submit`

Comment: mymodule_comment_form_submit() function is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the work around. first create a hook_form_alter function:

```
mymodule_form_alter($form,$form_state,$form_id){
       if ($form_id == 'comment_form') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_comment_form_submit';
   }
 }
```

Then create hook_comment_form_submit function and do your modification:

```
mymodule_comment_form_submit($form, $form_state){
     $form_state['values']['comment'] = myfunciton($form_state['values']);
 comment_save($form_state['values']); 
}
```

I dont know whether it is a good idea or not but I found few of post in which this approach is used.